# Vue SSR и NPM скрипты

Tags: node.js, vue.js, mongodb, npm

Ситуация такая...Для работы VUE-SSR собирается 2 бандла - один для сервера, другой для фронта. При каждом изменении кода они должны быть пересобраны... для того чтобы нормально разрабатывать, для автоматической пересборки этих бандлов висят ватчеры (watch). Помимо этого, у меня еще запускается сервер, тоже с ватчером (отдельно для файлов бэкенда) + мне нужно запустить Монгу.
Если я запускаю проект через команду `npm`, которая объединяет в себе несколько команд `npm run one && npm run two && npm run three`, то в случае, если первая команда с ватчером, то следующая не запускается.

В итоге, для того, чтобы запустить проект, мне необходимо открыть 4 терминала и запустить 4 npm команды. 1) Запуск Монги; 2) Запуск сервера; 3) Сборка серверного бандла Vue; 4) сборка клиентского бандла Vue. Это немного напрягает.

Кто может подсказать как выйти из ситуации?

```
  "scripts": {
    "build-client": "webpack  --config build/webpack.client.config.js --progress  --watch --hide-modules",
    "build-serv": "webpack --config build/webpack.server.config.js --progress --watch --hide-modules ",
    "serv": "supervisor --watch backend index.js "
  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отличным решением будет пакет [npm-run-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all). Он дает возможность использовать такие CLI утилиты:

- run-s `run-s one two three` - выполнит последовательно ваши команды, как сейчас у вас
- run-p `run-p one two three` - выполнит параллельно ваши команды, то есть как вам и надо